# Running two applications on a VPS using nginx passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm hosing a rails application on digital ocean. Its working perfectly. I would like to host a Sinatra application on the same VPS. I have setup the nameservers and DNS.

My `opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` is:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc6;
    passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  domain1.com;
    charset utf-8;
    root /home/deploy/apps/domain1/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_spawn_method smart;
    rails_env production;
    }
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  domain2.com www.domain2.com;
    charset utf-8;
    root /home/deploy/apps/domain2-path/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_spawn_method smart;
    }
}
```

Now when I go domain2.com it loads the application of domain1.com, what am I doing wrong.

PS: Domain1.com is rails applicion and Domain2.com is sinatra application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it only by defining another DNS address.
You should run the other app on different URL.

Then do something like this:

```
upstream rails {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

upstream sinatra {
    server 127.0.0.1:7000;
}

server {
    location /rails {
        proxy_pass http://rails;
    }
    location /sinatra {
        proxy_pass http://sinatra;
    }
}
```